# how to get the jpf heuristic live count when using Verify API

Tags: jpf

I am using something like

int y = Verify.getIntFromList(intArray);
boolean z = Verify.getBoolean();

//do something with y and z  i.e. all possible permutations of y and z etc.

I am interested in getting the live count of jpf as it go through each permutation. For example if there are 10 ints in the intArray and we know false and true for boolean so there will be total of 20 permutations. but I want live count as it is going through all of the 20 one by one. Want to use this live count in my program.

Hope I have explained clearly what I want to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before your above statements, call 
    Verify.setCounter(0,0);
Each time you call a Verify.getXXX()  call Verify.incrementCounter(0,1);

first argument in the counter statements is the counter index, you can define more than one counter and increment each one based on your logic.

counters are something like static variables of JPF.